# Bending line in 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, 3d, rotating

I would like to bend a line between two points in 3 dimensions. However, the argument `bend left` doesn't seem to allow me to choose which direction I would like this bend to occur. In the below MWE I would like the bend to occur in the z dimension rather than in the y dimension as it currently seems to do by default. How can I do this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{130},  % 120
xmin=0, xmax=1.1,
zmin=0, zmax=1.,
ymin=0, ymax=1.15,
clip=false,
rotate around z=0,
rotate around y=0,
rotate around x=0,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
zlabel={$z$}]
\node[draw] at (0.8, 0, 0.0) {Point 1};
\node[draw] at (0.5, 0, 0.) {Point 2};
\draw [-{Cone[width'=+0pt +1.0]}] (0.8, 0, 0.0) to[bend left=45] (0.5, 0, 0.);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You could fake 3D using something like `to[in=35, out=65]`, but I have to admit that I don't understand the diagram. Wouldn't the *z* dimension just go upwards, so `to[bend right=45]`?

Comment: @JasperHabicht That is ok, but really I would like to just have it correct in 3d (in case I wish to change the perspective later). It appears that the `bend left` is applied to the second dimension, maybe there is a way to reorder the dimensions being passed to the draw command? Or maybe there is a 3d version of draw I am not aware of?

Comment: @JasperHabicht To clarify, the z dimension is coming out of the screen (I would change the perspective once I have the arrow bending correctly)

Comment: You can always draw a path as curve using 3D coordinates , such as `\draw (0.8, 0, 0.0) .. controls (0.7, 0, 0.2) and (0.6, 0, 0.2) .. (0.5, 0, 0.0);`. The options `bend left/right` and `in/out` don't allow for 3D specifications as far as I know, but everything will actually be converted into 2D sooner or later.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't seem to go through the desired points

Comment: The curve won't go through the two coordinates specified with `controls`, but they are needed to define it. See https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.4